# Testing Play 2.0 Controllers inside sub-packages

Tags: testing, playframework-2.0

Picking up again with Play!, now using 2.0.3-RC2, I'm having a testing issue.

I have an application with some controllers packaged under controllers package, for example:

```
package controllers.AdminApp;

class SomeController extends Controller {
    public void index() {
        /...
}
```

And according to documentation in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaFunctionalTest, I would expect a test for this controller, with something like :

```
Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.AdminApp.SomeController.index());
```

But doesn't work because there's no SomeController as member of controllers.routes.ref.AdminApp, only ReverseAdminApp_SomeController and can't call the index() method from there.

Do you have any experience testing Play 2.0 Java controllers within sub-packages?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading for 2.1.0 and realized also that intelliJ did not helped me to figure out the problem.

```
Result result = callAction(controllers.adminApp.routes.ref.Application.index());
```